# Is there a JQuery plugin that lets the browser scroll down to 200 pixels from the current position, smoothly?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, templates, plugins

The plugin should make the scroll bar go down 200 pixels, from the current position. But very smoothly, and kind of cool too ,but not too much.

Comment: "kind of cool too ,but not too much" That's a technical spec I take it?

Answer (score 3):

You don't need a plugin for that purpose, just use jQuery's `.animate()`:

```
$(window).animate({scrollTop: '+=200'}, 2000);
```

You can replace `window` with any element/node that <strike>owns a scrollbar</strike>. has a scrollable content.

Ref.: [.animate()](http://api.jquery.com/animate/)

Example: http://www.jsfiddle.net/4yUqL/28/

Answer (score 1):

Cool, but not too cool: http://flesler.blogspot.com/2007/10/jqueryscrollto.html

Demos: http://demos.flesler.com/jquery/scrollTo/